# Image not display using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, image

Below is my code for display information of an image including its file, but this is not displaying, I don't know why.

```
 <?php
      include('config/dbconnect.php');  
      if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
      { 
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM collage WHERE id = '$id'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                  $name = $row['name'];
                  $content = $row['content'];
                  $size = $row['size'];
                  $type = $row['type'];
                  $date_upload = $row['date_upload'];
                  $file = $row['file'];
            }
      }
?>
<div class='body-content'>
<div class='img-name-cont'><h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3></div>
<div class='img-detail-cont'>upload: <?php echo $date_upload; ?><br>type: <?php echo $type; ?><br>size: <?php echo $size; ?>KB </div>
<div class='img-file-cont'>
<img src="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" style="width:130px; height:100%"></div>
<div class='img-content-cont'><?php echo $content; ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: view page source -- is the HTML correct?

Comment: do you get any error code in code inspector?? PS: your code can be injected by sql injection

Comment: After `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` And write `$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM collage WHERE id = '$id'") or die (mysqli_error($con));` and check for errors

Comment: missing `;` at `<?php echo $row['file'] ?>'

Comment: check the given path name is correct

Comment: hello guys .. as i checked in view source .. only the path of an image . no image file.

Comment: thank you guys .. you made it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all use inspect to check whether the image is actually pointed to by the code. that is the actual loation might not be pointed at. what is your folder structure.

" style="width:130px; height:100%">

your code is ok. as long as **php echo $row['file']** returns a file

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is "Your all the variables are local to the while loop". so you can't access it outside of the while loop. Try this code.

```
 <?php
      include('config/dbconnect.php');  
      if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
      { 
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM collage WHERE id = '$id'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?> 

                  <div class='body-content'>
                  <div class='img-name-cont'><h3><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h3></div>
                  <div class='img-detail-cont'>upload: <?php echo $row['date_upload']; ?><br>type: 
                  <?php echo $row['type']; ?><br>size: <?php echo $row['size']; ?>KB </div>
                  <div class='img-file-cont'>
                  <img src="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file']; ?>" style="width:130px; height:100%"></div>
                  <div class='img-content-cont'><?php echo $row['content']; ?></div>
                  </div>
        <?php
            }
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Dulaj Sanjaya all your `variables` are `local` so you can't use that outside of `while`.

Second if you want to use your code then you have taken all data of `$row` in different `variables` then used outside of file then why don't you used same `$file` for `image` why you have used `$row['file']`?

Simply replace this line as

```
<div class='img-file-cont'>
                  <img src="img/collage/<?php echo $file; ?>" style="width:130px; height:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check `echo $row['file']` if it returns the correct string of your image path **with the correct file extension** .

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one :
first of all you have to check if your image path ok or not using this php function:
```

`<?php
     $img=getimagesize($imagewithpath);
      if($img=="") 
      { echo "there is no image ";} 
 else{  ?> <img src="<?php echo $imagewithpath; ?>" style="width:130px; height:100%">  <?php  } ?>`